# COVID-19 pandemic as mitigating factor for sentencing in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, case-law

Are there any cases from the UK, whether from the Supreme Court or any other courts, saying that the COVID-19 pandemic can be considered as a mitigating factor for sentencing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

[R v Manning](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Crim/2020/592.html) includes the following (my emphasis)

> We would mention one other factor of relevance. We are hearing this
> Reference at the end of April 2020, when the nation remains in
> lock-down as a result of the Covid-19 emergency. The impact of that
> emergency on prisons is well-known...

> The current conditions in prisons represent a factor which can properly be taken
> into account in deciding whether to suspend a sentence. In accordance
> with established principles, any court will take into account the
> likely impact of a custodial sentence upon an offender and, where
> appropriate, upon others as well. **Judges and magistrates can,
> therefore, and in our judgment should, keep in mind that the impact of
> a custodial sentence is likely to be heavier during the current
> emergency than it would otherwise be**. Those in custody are, for
> example, confined to their cells for much longer periods than would
> otherwise be the case – currently, 23 hours a day. They are unable to
> receive visits. Both they and their families are likely to be anxious
> about the risk of the transmission of Covid-19.